# Class Method not running in another thread despite background worker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, methods, backgroundworker

On a button press I call a background worker to change the colour of some text, and in the DoWork method it creates a new object and executes one of its methods. Here is the code:

```
    private void StartProcessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FirstTimeBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(GenKeyLabel.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue);

    }
```

And the DoWork method...

```
    private void FirstTimeBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {  
        KeyFile k = new KeyFile();
        k.CreateDummyFile(DLetter);

    }
```

*[The CreateDummyFile effectively does a bunch of file processing, such as copying,deleting and creating files (up to 4.0MB). Throughout I call the ReportProgress method and change some GUI elements on the form, however as it does it in one chunk I cant see the constant progress or the GUI elements change]*

Now it does what its supposed to inside the CreateDummyFile method, however it executes it as if it wasn't in another thread (like when you press a button to do something and the form would freeze, and then just show the final result). Any ideas why this is? What I am doing wrong?

There is a lot of code in that class that gets executed so I can't just place it inside the DoWork method.

**EDIT:** Removed all of the ReportProgress's and it still only changes one of my GUI elements. (All I do is change the font.forecolour. Apart from this I am changing the text on a status strip...

Comment: You are calling ReportProgress() too often, flooding the GUI thread with invoke requests.  Too busy with them, it will stop doing the low priority stuff.  Like painting.  Only invoke at human eye speed, no more than once every 50 msec.

Comment: I will remove them and see if this resolves it. Check main post edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `FirstTimeBackgroundWorker_DoWork` as a handler of `DoWork` event on BackgroundWorker:

`FirstTimeBackgroundWorker.DoWork += FirstTimeBackgroundWorker_DoWork;`

Also make sure if you're calling back the UI to update it to do so on the UI thread, not from the background one.

Comment: Out of the house, will do this in a few hours! Thank you! I will write back!

Comment: Ok the KeyFile calls back to the UI via a Public Function. I am not quite sure what you mean by adding it as a handler as it is already made as the event for the DoWork event from the control... I added that line of code to the DoWork event, however no differece, please be more specific.. Thank you!